# HTML tables like LaTeX tabbing; last column of each row should span the entire table

Tags: html, css, latex

I would like a table in HTML which looks like this:

```
C1  Some text right here
    C2  Some text here too
        C3  And maybe some text here
    C4  Basically like a text written with tabbing
C5  You get the point?
```

I know I could probably use a list here, but I want the columns (except the last one on each row) to have a fixed width. In LaTeX, this would work:

```
\newenvironment{mytable}
{\begin{tabbing}
xxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxx\=\kill}
{\end{tabbing} }%

mytable{
C1 \> Some text right here \+\\
  C2 \> Some text here too \+\\
    C3 \> And maybe some text here \-\\
  C4 \> Basically like a text written with tabbing \-\\
C5 \> You get the point?
}
```

I tried doing this in HTML/CSS, but the result would look like this:

```
C1  Some text right here
                          C2  Some text here too
                                                  C3  etc...
```

Any tips?

Comment: No time at the moment for a real answer, but: The way to go would still be to use lists (like `<ul>` or `<ol>` in HTML and styles these elements accordingly (`display: block`, `width`, `margin`, and `padding` are some keywords to search for)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution, which seems to do the trick. Here's the CSS:

```
div.start
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 60px;
}
ul.tabbing
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.tabbing li ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="tabbing">
  <li><div class="start">C1</div>Some text right here
  <ul>
    <li><div class="start">C2</div>Some text here too
    <ul>
      <li><div class="start">C3</div>And maybe some text here</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><div class="start">C4</div>Basically like a text written with tabbing</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li><div class="start">C5</div>You get the point?</li>
</ul>
```

It's not exactly as explained in the question (close though), but solves the specified problem I had.

Answer (score 4):

**Firstly this is a really bad abuse of tables and should be avoided really.** (bolded because I feel very strongly about this). :)

Secondly the problem you have is that you need colspanning to do it properly. You've not actually shown the html that you have used but the example looks like you are just putting empty table cells in front of things but because of how tables work this means that the next cell is starting after the end of all the contents in the first cell.

The way to do it therefore is to structure your table like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="3">First line</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td colspan="2">second line</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td>third line</td></tr>
</table>
```

Example with some styling: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd4Mx/
The idea is that the first line spans the whole table. The second line has a single table cell and then the rest of the line spans the whole table, etc.

For more rows you'll need more columns in your table but this is a rough idea.

Lastly a better way to do indenting is to just use `div` elements with margins.

```
<style>
div.indent
{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
</style>

<div>
First line
    <div class="indent">Second line
        <div class="indent">Third line</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example in same fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd4Mx/

Comment: I also thought about using indentation first, but I need the first part of the row (after the indentation, `Cx` in the example) to be the same (fixed) width. `colspan` works fine, but I thought that there would perhaps be a more elegant way. Perhaps a combination of identation divs and fixed width divs? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Ah, hadn't twigged that the Cx was in its own table cell. If the content after Cx wraps to a new line can it go under the Cx or should it be equally indented? Either way using a couple of divs using `display: inline-block;` should do the trick. Just oen for teh Cx if the text can wrap below it or a second for the content to keep it lined up if needed.